# Why can't I get any output in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I just created a form and am trying to get the values of the form elements what is wrong with this code that I am using?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                font-family:ebrima;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
            Username: <input type="text" id="nameSpace"><br />
            Password: <input type="text" style="margin-left:5px;" id="passSpace"><br />
            <button type="button" onClick="login()" name="login" style="margin-left:210px;" value="Login">Login!</button>
        </form> 
            <p id="demo"></p>

            <script>
            function login() {
                var username = document.getElementById('nameSpace').value;
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=username;
            }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should note that `onClick` events are not the preferred way of writing javascript. Instead you should attach the handlers with JS, this is a concept known as *unobtrusive javascript*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function has the same name as an element's id/name. It is being overwritten by a reference to the DOM object.

First spend 10 minutes cursing Microsoft for leaving us with this legacy, then rename the function.

---

As a better solution, in general:

1. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead of using intrinsic event attributes
2. Avoid using globals.

Such:

```
<button type="button" id="login" name="login" style="margin-left:210px;" value="Login">Login!</button>
```

and

```
(function () { // Immediately invoked function for the purposes of limiting scope
    function login() {
        var username = document.getElementById('nameSpace').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=username;
    }
    document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', login);
})();
```

Note [compatibility issues with old IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility).

Comment: `Your function has the same name as an element's id` You mean the function has the same name as the element's `name`? The element doesn't have an `ID`. Also, why is everyone downvoting? It's a good and witty answer!

Comment: What is getting overridden by what? I don't see it. And what are you saying is the legacy?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer — `function login()` is being overwritten by `<button name="login"`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer — It is a legacy from Microsoft because they thought it was a good idea for every element with an id/name to create a global variable to match when they brought out IE4 and we've been stuck with it ever since.

Comment: Oh dear god. I didn't know about that! Any idea what version of IE that stopped at?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I don't think it has -- which is why it's become a legacy.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer — It hasn't stopped. So many people wrote code that depended on it that other browsers adopted it for for compatibility and it spread into the HTML 5 specification.

Comment: @jfriend00 — If I take the OP's code and replace the call to `login` with a `console.log()` of it — http://jsbin.com/uROkUnI/1/ — then it logs the DOM object. Possibly there is a related issue of scope within an onclick attribute rather then a global. The solutions are the same though.

Comment: @Quentin - yeah, I see that.  Weird.  In many other cases (such as in my jsFiddle), the implicit global symbol is simply overwritten when you define your own.  OK, I withdrew my comment.